# Send data to Express backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having trouble sending data to the Backend. I want to send data `f1` to `QueryBackend.js` but when I try to `console.log(req.body.f1)` it's always undefined but in `Services.js` get the value.

Toolbar.js

```
handlePrintLetter = async(fieldName, fieldValue) => {
  const { formId, selectedRows, displayData, onNotification } = this.props;
  const idSelected = selectedRows.data.map(d => displayData[d.dataIndex].id);
  const res = await getBookmarkDocument(idSelected);  // Send Data to Backend
  if (res.success) {
    onNotification({ mode: 'success', text: 'success' });
  } else {
    onNotification({ mode: 'error', text: fieldName + ' ' + fieldValue });
  }
}
```

Service.js

```
export const getBookmarkDocument = async (f1) => {
  console.log(f1) // get value from Toolbar.js
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  return axios.get(API + 'doc/show', { f1 },
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  })
    .then((response) => response.data || [])
    .catch((error) => {
      ErrorAPI(error);
      return [];
    });
}
```

How to get data `f1` in here?

QueryBackend.js

```
router.get('/show', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body.f1)  // undefined
    const pool = await poolPromise;
    const result = await pool.query('SELECT sid_ddocument_key FROM sid_ddocument WHERE sid_ddocument_key = $1', ['I WANNA PUT DATA 'f1' IN HERE']);  // Put Data f1
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: result.rows
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      response: err.message
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: so, req doesn't have the body, try sending value using query string as directed in the answer. This should work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET requests can't have bodies. Encode the data in the query string and read it with `req.query`

```js
const f1 = 'example';
const API = 'http://example.com/';
const url = new URL(`${API}doc/show`);
url.searchParams.append("f1", f1);
console.log(url.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you, I got the value from `console.log(req.query.f2)`